# Is there a simple one line way to exclude the first element of a range function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just for clarification, the step can also be negative. I'm currently just doing this.

```
def excl_range(start, end, step):
    if step > 0:
        return range(start + 1, end, step)
    return range(start - 1, end, step)
```

I'm Just wondering if there is a cleaner way preferably without the use of a new function to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rarely mentioned or used fact about [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is that it is a complete [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) in python 3. That means that you can index objects directly, including with slices:

```
range(...)[1:]
```

This is equivalent to incrementing `start` by `step`. Notice that the sign of step is irrelevant: the second element is always `start + step` by definition:

```
range(start + step, end, step)
```

You can also exclude the element during iteration:

```
it = iter(range(...))
next(it)
for x in it:
    ...
```

This works for any [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), not just `range`. You can do the equivalent with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
for x in islice(range(...), 1):
    ...
```

Comment: Ahh that's exactly what I was looking for, range(...)[1:], since the other 2 wouldn't exactly work very cleanly in my context. Thank you very much ill accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @SamTaaghol. I've also added a much cleaner version of your original attempt

Comment: The thing about that is the "step"  is very long and I'm a bit of a line freak, trying to make it as clean as possible haha. that why I resorted to using the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider doing it like this:-

```
step = 1
start = 10
end = 100

for i in range(start + 1 if step > 0 else start - 1, end, step):
    pass # your code goes here
```

Comment: Just realized you can slice the range directly

Comment: @darkknight You probably meant `start + step`, not `start + 1`.

Comment: Also, because of that, there's no conditional. I've added that to my answer now

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille No. Take another look at the OP's code

Comment: Well, the OP's original code is wrong on that aspect, and doesn't do what the question asks.